# .NET Fastest way to do checked arithmetic

Tags: c#, .net

I have this bit of code in a critical path of my application

```
try
{
    checked
    {
        values[i] = (int)(sample[i].Value * (double)magnitude));
    }
} catch (OverflowException)
{
    values[i] = int.MaxValue;
}
```

However, once the magnitude gets high enough (around 1.8 ish), this section starts to throw OverflowExceptions like crazy and significantly slows down my app. Changing this block to unchecked gets rid of the issue so I know this is the problem.

What is the fastest/cheapest way to do checked arithmetic where you have a default value if it overflows?

Comment: I imagine the exception occurs on the cast to `int`? If so you could add a check to see if the value is greater than `int.MaxValue`

Comment: @Igor The use of the `checked` keyword causes it to throw the exception, not the cast. Removing the `checked` means the `OverflowException` won't be thrown, but the value will be nonsense since it overflowed.

Comment: @mmathis See Igor's answer for that. `checked` throws the exception because it's designed to, it has to be manually validated and assigned a default value if it's an overflow.

Comment: @mmathis since the multiplication is done against a double the resulting value would be a double, which is far less likely to overflow than the cast to int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception occurs on the cast to `int` if the value is greater than the maximum value of an int. You could add a check to see if the value is greater than `int.MaxValue`. If you ever expect a negative value you should also check against `int.MinValue`.

```
var result = (sample[i].Value * (double)magnitude);
values[i] = result > int.MaxValue ? int.MaxValue : (int)result;
```

[.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRezpl)